# Django access information model with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

my models.py

```
class Information(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    published = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Search(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    searched_titles = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    searched_topics = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number_found_articles = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class Article_search(models.Model):
    found_articles = models.ForeignKey(
        Information, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, primary_key=True)
    search_details = models.ForeignKey(
        Search, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my views.py

```
def show_articles_with_this_filter_id(request):
    alles = Article_search.objects.all()
    print(alles)
```

the error i get: (1054, "1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'database_article_search.found_articles_id' in 'field list'", '42S22')

if i make my models.py Article_search class like this:

```
class Article_search(models.Model):
    found_articles = models.ForeignKey(
        Information, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    search_details = models.ForeignKey(
        Search, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I get this error: (1054, "1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'database_article_search.id' in 'field list'", '42S22')

I know every models needs a primary key, but i don't understand why all give an error. Please can someone help me to access the data from this model

After suggestions i made the models.py file like:

```
class Information(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    published = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Search(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    searched_titles = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    searched_topics = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number_found_articles = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class Article_search(models.Model):
    found_articles = models.OneToOneField(
        Information,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,)
    search_details = models.OneToOneField(
        Search, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

when i try to fetch all information from the Article_search table with views.py i get the error: (1054, "1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'database_article_search.found_articles_id' in 'field list'", '42S22')

Comment: Have you run migrations?

Comment: I have, also i have deleted all the old migrations files, so everything is like i want it to be, except for the error

Comment: Check @Darsh Modi's answer.

Comment: Yes I see, still i'm not sure why django tries to find database_article_search.found_articles_id. this + _id field is put after a variable i did name, database_article_search.found_articles_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key can never be a primary key for other models, to achieve that you have to use **OneToOne** field instead of the foreign key.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I know have: class Article_search(models.Model): found_articles = models.OneToOneField(Information,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
primary_key=True,)  search_details = models.OneToOneField(Search, on_delete=models.CASCADE). still i get the error: 'database_article_search.found_articles_id' in 'field list'

Comment: I just had to change the fields to manytomany and add an id field. I struggeled very long with this question. Thank you for answering and taking the time to read and think about it.

Comment: @Brit You're most welcome and happy to help you, buddy.

Comment: I used a many to many field, because articles can appear in multiple searches and searches can find multiple articles. Still this field seems to give some error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71270632/manytomanyfield-makes-an-incorrect-model